# Multiple models for one single wallet

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, expected-return, intraday

I am an algorithm day trader. I am trying to automate certain patterns on the stock markets. Here is my question. Suppose I have $n$ models $M_1, M_2, M_3, \dots, M_n$ with expected return  $E_1, E_2, E_3, \dots, E_n$. Each of those models can be triggered at any time. Suppose I have a wallet of $X$ dollars. How can I handle the models using that wallet? If $M_i$ is triggered, I can't take the whole $X$ dollars for one single trade. If so, then if $M_j$ is triggered, then I can't trade because my wallet has $0$ dollar in it. In addition, as I use my portfolio for only one trade, then I put myself more at risk than if I used more than one (diversification). Is there a mathematical way to deal with that?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the one of the main objective functions any Algo trader has to think of? How have you done it now? Automating Your current approach by finding a formula that describes your current behavior would not be an option?

Comment: Since you have the expected returns you can use Kelly Criterion, or depending on what other data you have you can use ranking for allocation.

Comment: You can try to combine the models using off-the-shelf [machine learning methods](http://stanfordphd.com/Machine_Learning.html), like [random forests](http://stanfordphd.com/RandomForest.html). Stay away for methods requiring too much fine-tuning, e.g. neural networks.